# Can I add variables of unknown name, but known types in type of TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and have been searching the internet for quite a bit but unsure of the terminology.

I am currently using a React-form-hook library, that requires the variable types to be specified (ie:

```
type FormData = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

and I am adding a number of inputs based on the number of elements I have in an array. Thus, I would like to know if there is a way to add to the above code in the same format? Since, the names of the variables are unknown, but they are of string type. Something like

```
type FormData = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  nameOfFirstElement: string
  nameOfSecondElement: string
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I have to give them a name individually?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks weird, could you store them in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is with Record:

```
type FormData = Record<string, string>
```